# What changed between kernels 3.2 and 3.9 that affect MiniDLNA?

Tags: debian, kernel, dlna

I'm using Debian testing, and I've problems with MiniDLNA on kernel > 3.2. The DLNA client works about 30 min, after that it lost the connection with the minidlna server and can't discover the server again.

But if I load with an old kernel (3.2) all works fine. The time that minidlna works (30 min) may be related to the notify_interval parameter, which by default is 15 min.

**Problem solved**. It was related to my network configuration. My network config:

```
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.5.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.5.1

    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 0
    bridge_fd 0
```

In 3.5 kernel was [added multicast_querier toggle and disabled queries by default](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/net/bridge/br_multicast.c?id=c5c23260594c5701af66ef754916775ba6a46bbc) which broke my DLNA on bridge interface.

Now I just enable multicast_querier and all works as before.

```
# echo 1 > /sys/class/net/br0/bridge/multicast_querier
```

Comment: This should be reopened and hopefully sorted into a Q&A.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and adding the solution @abobov. The question should be reopened soon, it would be great if you could post your solution as an answer and accept it once it has been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was related to my network configuration. My network config:

```
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.5.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.5.1

    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 0
    bridge_fd 0
```

In 3.5 kernel was [added multicast_querier toggle and disabled queries by default](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/net/bridge/br_multicast.c?id=c5c23260594c5701af66ef754916775ba6a46bbc) which broke my DLNA on bridge interface.

Now I just enable multicast_querier and all works as before.

```
# echo 1 > /sys/class/net/br0/bridge/multicast_querier
```